# How to create a form in django using ChoiceField in foms.py

Tags: python, django

I have to build a form where I want a drop down menu list, what will be the procedure.

If u can then plz do tell me the stepwise procedur coz I am a beginner in python. example, what code to be written in views.py, forms.py and urls.py etc.

Thanks in advance................Byeee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choices are easy to specify manually (or, for that matter, programatically) in Django.

This depicts a model, which will in turn have a dropdown selector in a ModelForm:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

You can do the same thing in a regular form.

Comment: Thanks buddy u made me understand that,,,,,,,,,,,